# Linux fill all files recursivelly with random or pseudo random data

Tags: linux, random, byte, fill, dd

I want to fill with random bytes ALL files RECURSIVELLY from the root directory. ONLY FILES, folders are to be left untoutched

I DON´T WANT TO DELETE the files, just fill them with random bytes

In my research, the fill command for a single file could be something like:

`dd if=/dev/random of=target-files bs=1M`

And to find all files recursivelly I should use:

`find . -name "* .*"`

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to achieve my goal by joining this two commands?
   (pipe them? how?)
2. Is there another easier way to achieve the same results?

Thanks for any help ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the "rando" typo in the title, the correct should be Linux fill all files recursivelly with random or pseudo random data

Comment: When you say **fill**. Do you want them to retain their size, or clobber them and make them the same size?

Comment: Each file must retain their original size.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to pipe the find result to while loop, and dd /dev/udrandom into each files.

```
$ find myfolder -type f |while read fd; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=$fd bs=1M count=1;done
```

If you want to retain file size, may do some calculation on finding 1k block count and pass as args in dd.

```
$ find myfolder -type f|while read fd; do FSIZ=`stat -c %s $fd`; CNT=`expr $FSIZ / 1024`;dd if=/dev/urandom of=$fd bs=1k count=$CNT;done
```

Comment: Thanks. This way is almost there :-) But it resizes all files to 1M. Is it possible to achieve the same goal while retaining each file original size ?

Comment: @LinuxLearnerfromS.A. add logic to find file size and dd same file size.

Comment: Thank you all. Ronald Poon sugestion did it.

Comment: If you want to write only the first Nbytes (in this case, 1024*1024bytes=1MiB) but you want to preserve the file size, you can use the *conv* parameter on **dd**; like this: `dd if=somefile of=otherfile conv=notrunc`

Answer (score 0):

Find + xargs + dd + wc would do that.

```
 find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -Ifilename  sh -c 'dd if=/dev/urandom of="filename" bs=`wc -c "filename" | cut -d" " -f1` count=1'
```

How it works:

1. find + xargs iterate over all files starting from /
2. -print0 in find + -0 in xargs deal with edge cases like blank spaces / quotes / hyphen in filename etc
3. "wc -c" provide size of file in bytes, cut extracts first word from output that has size in bytes
4. dd fills output file with size provided by wc + cut
5. -I in xargs specifies the variable for filenames

Comment: Your answer was able to deal with spaces in file names! Thank you very much you guys are geniuses

Comment: some filenames are tricky to deal with, like those with spaces / semicolons / quotes / hyphens.

Comment: And if i needed to adapt this command that deals with spaces in file names to set a specific date to all files? Like **touch -d '2010-01-01 00:00:00'** Can you be so king to tell me the comand line for that ;-)

Comment: This command should work with file like "'2010-01-01 00:00:00'" since "filename" variable is quoted before it is passed as an argument to dd and wc.

Answer (score 0):

And a third approach :)

```
find / -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | while read size name ; do dd if=/dev/urandom of="${name}" bs=1c count=${size}; done
```

Be prepared to wait a LONG time :}

Answer (score 0):

I love **dd** (really: I love it!); but, in this case, you can use **shred**,  especially designed for achieve something like this.
It's part of the *GNU coreutils* package (installed on [almost] all linux systems).

> `find rootdirectory -type f -print0 | xargs --null --max-args=1 shred --force --iterations=4 --random-source=/dev/urandom --verbose`